# Ошибка в обращении к SharedPreferences

Tags: android

Строка   `dateSH = sPref.getInt(SAVED_DATE, 0);`
Вызывает ошибку. Как я понимаю это из-за пустого SharedPreferences. Но ведь дефолтное значение указано, в чем может быть проблема?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.content.SharedPreferences.getInt(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Кажется, у Вас сам `sPref` не инициализирован

Comment: проблема действительно в этом, спасибо!